# How to broadcast third dimension in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a sobel filter

```
sobel_x = tf.constant([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]], tf.float32)
```

I want to get a depth of 64. The shape is momentarily [3,3,1], but it should result in [3,3,64].

How do to that? With the following line, I get shape errors.

```
tf.tile(sobel_x, [1, 1, 64])



ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [3,3], [3].
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot broadcast is that the third dimension does not exist, and so you actually have a rank 2 tensor.

```
>>> sess.run(tf.shape(sobel_x))
array([3, 3], dtype=int32)
```

We can solve this problem by reshaping the tensor first.

```
>>> sobel_x = tf.reshape(sobel_x, [3, 3, 1])
>>> tf.tile(sobel_x, [1, 1, 64])
<tf.Tensor 'Tile_6:0' shape=(3, 3, 64) dtype=float32>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with sobel_x.

`sobel_x.get_shape(): TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(3)])`
`sobel_x: <tf.tensor 'Const:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float32`

So sobel_x is a two dimension matrix and your passing a rank 3 input to tile hence the error.

Fix: Make sobel_x 3 dimensional such that the shape is `shape=(3, 3, 1)`
then `tf.tile(sobel_x, [1, 1, 64]` will output `shape=(1, 1, 64)`